# Unable to Connect to Azure MySQL using MySQL Work Bench

Tags: mysql, database, azure, cloud, mysql-workbench

I create a MySQL storage in Microsoft Azure. What I did is from the portal I clicked "New > Data+Storage > MySQL". The I kept the defaults and continued. After everything Azure says the storage and all is now ready.

So, I went to "DashBoard > Clicked on my newly created database resource". Now I can see my IP address of the database.

I opened MySQL Work Bench, clicked  "Database >Connect to Database" and inserted the IP I found in my above step. I kept port 3306 as it is. For the user name and password I inserted the username and password I inserted during my database creation.

Anyway I really can't connect to the database, I get the below error.
[image]

I even tried editing my "Security Group" in Azure. Below is a screenshot of what it contains now.

Inbound Rules:
[image]

Outbound Rules
[image]

Even after all of these things, why I still can't connect to Azure MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using 'Bitnami' and 'Bitnami' comes with their own username and password! The default password for Bitnami is 'bitnami' and user name is 'root'